# How to restart cloudify manager and its components

Tags: cloudify

I have added the env variable CFY_WORKDIR (in /etc/environment) to change the current working directory. In my understanding to take this new directory into effect, I need to restart the cloudify manager. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2):

for the followup questions in comments, you can update `TMPDIR` environment variable in 
`/etc/sysconfig/cloudify-restservice` and `/etc/sysconfig/cloudify-mgmtworker`, then restart the services using `sudo systemctl restart cloudify-restservice` and `sudo systemctl restart cloudify-mgmtworker`.

updating config.yaml is also an option for mgmtworker, but only before running `cfy_manager install`.

Answer (score 1):

The 'CFY_WORKDIR' is specifically to change the working directory for the CLI components. Therefore, this is independent of the Manager and you will not need to restart anything. You can try running 'cfy profiles use MANAGER_IP' again to connect to the running manager and see if that works.

Jeremy

Comment: Thank you, currently Cloudify deploys all the blueprints in /tmp directory and executes from there. Is it possible to change the Cloudify to deploy the files in some other directory

Comment: The way to do that is to add `CFY_EXEC_TEMP` and `TMPDIR` environment variables in the mgmtworker env with the path to the new tmp directory.

You can also define it pre-installation in the `config.yaml` file:
mgmtworker: 
    extra_env: 
        CFY_EXEC_TEMP: /newtmp
        TMPDIR: /newtmp

Comment: Thank you, will try and let you know

Comment: I have added the env variables in config.yaml. And reset the profiles.However still it uses the /tmp directory.

Comment: @VishwaDany see below

Comment: Thank you, will check and let you know